# node access permission

Tags: blocks

i have created a custom block where i retrieve few fields value from a content of specific content-type(called project)and display it as a card in the site. but i don't want users who have logged into the site to see the actual content of that content type. to do this i have enabled node access permission and disabled access to view content through node ui for that content-type. the issue is the custom block doesn't get the values from the content. how can i fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i did this 
$nids = $query
          ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1))
          ->execute();
and it fetched the value as an admin.